# How to disable light mode in Windows Phone

Tags: windows-phone-7

How to disable light mode in the Windows Phone. I do not like the idea somebody will change color in my application and then write in the certification that he sees nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't disable light or dark mode. You need to test your app with both themes as this is a certification requeriment.

Answer (score 2):

Of course you also do not need to use the system styles but instead your own colors for whatever you want.

Comment: Agreed. Manually style your app to match the dark theme.

Comment: Keep in mind that the on screen keyboard will still be white in white-mode.